# Do ruby-socketed helms work for Paragon experience?

Tags: diablo-iii

Do experience bonuses from rubied helms and helmets work for post-level 60 Paragon experience? How do rubied helms affect Paragon experience gain?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, +experience gems will affect Paragon leveling.

> One question a lot of players are asking is about + experience gems,
>   will this be working with the Paragon system?
>
> Yes, +experience does work with the Paragon system.

[Source](http://www.diablofans.com/topic/66001-patch-104-interview-with-jay-wilson-and-andrew-chambers/)

Comment: woah is this a way to bring back players? because it does seems tempting to me..

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the intent - give those who want to keep playing and playing after hitting 60 a way to do so.  After all there's plenty of people who went for level 99 in D2.

Comment: The problem was, as some blue post noticed, that pre 1.0.4 you could have been playing for 2 hours and end up with nothing but losses (no decent item found, and gold lost due to repair). That wasn't a really good experience so now with the paragon system you do make progress even though you may have lost gold and didn't improve your gear.